# Mean.js: why is Gulp overwriting changes to production.js

Tags: meanjs

Starting my Mean.js application using `gulp prod` is overwriting my changes to production.js. I edit the file, save it, commit it, whatever, and when I run `gulp prod` it immediately reverts to the state it was before I edited, linting errors and all. This is config/assets/production.js, which as far as I know is a source file, not something I'd expect to be generated.

I've searched the docs and the code to try to figure out what's happening, but I'm not getting it. Any hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This had been due to the 'wiredep' task overwriting the assets based on bower.json.